# adding custom palette to mui theme gives syntax error

Tags: material-ui, material-design

I try to simply add a new palette to my MUI Theme and get the following type error:

[image]

Any help or hint?

Answer (score 1):

It TypeScript error, if you want add new custom filed in palette, you need to declare them.
This error not happens if you want change color for primary: `{ main: 'red' }` or secondary: `{ light: 'white' }`, but when you want to add your custom fields, you need declare it first.

```
declare module '@mui/material/styles' {
    interface Palette {
        custom: {
            transparent: React.CSSProperties['color'];
        }
    }
    interface PaletteOptions {
        custom: {
            transparent: React.CSSProperties['color'];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not creating a new palette what I see in the image is that you are trying to overwrite the existing palette `object` by adding a new `property` 'custom' but this is not possible! the `interface` PaletteOptions does not have a property 'custom'.

if you want to use another palette you just have to replace the existing palette object with your new custom one.